# ssh not found when using variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Running into a weird error while writing a shell script.

The following works perfectly fine...

```
#!/bin/sh
if ssh root@example.com "[ -d /web ]"; then 
    echo "That directory exists!";
fi
```

And runs without error. Once I try using variables however...

```
#!/bin/sh
USER="root"
LOC="example.com"
PATH="/web"

if ssh $USER@$LOC "[ -d $PATH ]"; then 
    echo "That directory exists!";
fi
```

it just returns...

```
6: test.sh: ssh: not found
```

Even just setting the variables at the top and leaving the bottom hard coded makes it throw this error.

Answer (score 3):

[`$PATH`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) is being used by the local shell to find binaries, in this case `ssh`. As soon as you set it to `/web`, the shell will try to locate `/web/ssh` which does not exist.

Use a different variable name:

```
remote_path="/web"
```

Comment: You could explain how to add `web` to the PATH variable :) if he need it.

Comment: That does not make sense.